Using AppleScriptTask() in Excel's VBA macro to run python file, returning an "invalid procedure call or argument (error 5)"
Hi Stack Overflow community!
I'm working on a project to run a short python application in Excel. So far, I've written the following VBA code in Excel:
Sub RunPythonScriptUsingAppleScriptTask()
    Dim directoryPath As String, username As String, password As String, country As String
    
    ' Retrieve values from Excel
    directoryPath = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
    username = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
    password = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value
    country = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Value
    
    ' Build the arguments string
    Dim args As String
    args = directoryPath & "," & username & "," & password & "," & country
    
    ' Run the AppleScript
    Dim scriptResult As String
    scriptResult = AppleScriptTask("RunPythonScript.scpt", "Run", args)
    
    ' Debugging: Display the result or any returned value
    MsgBox scriptResult
End Sub

The script "RunPythonScript.scpt" is:
on splitString(inputString, delimiter)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to delimiter
    set stringItems to every text item of inputString
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "" -- Reset to default
    return stringItems
end splitString

on run argv
    set args to splitString(argv, ",")
    set directoryPath to item 1 of args
    set username to item 2 of args
    set password to item 3 of args
    set country to item 4 of args
    
    set shellCommand to "/Users/sunnywong/chathamFinancial/venv/bin/python3 /Users/sunnywong/chathamFinancial/extractRates.py " & directoryPath & " " & username & " " & password & " " & country
    do shell script shellCommand
end run

Where the function splitString() is to split the input string from the VBA code into seperate arguments.
When I run the VBA code, I get an "invalid procedure call or argument (error 5)", highlighting the line "scriptResult = AppleScriptTask("RunPythonScript.scpt", "Run", args)".
I've tried the following:

Ensuring the shell command and the arguments are correct by explictly running the command in terminal. (it works)
Ensuring the script file is in the ~/library/Application Scripts/com.microsoft.Excel directory. (it is)
Ensuring that under Excel > Preferences > Security > Macro Security, "Enable all macros" is checked. (it is)

Something I haven't been able to try is going into my Mac's system settings > Privacy & Security > Automation and unchecking "finder" for Excel because Excel isn't listed as an option in that section.
In all of my efforts I've received the same error, and the debugger points to the same line.

Apple has stopped actively working to improve AppleScript, with the last major changes made in macOS 10.11 over four years ago. I suggest you find an alternative.
